# Union sub-query left join - too slow

Tags: sql-server, union

This query never finishes...

```sql
select u.anUserId, u.acUserId, u.acTitle, u.acActive, activeUsers365.* 
from tPA_User u
    left join (

        select distinct u.anuserid, u.acUserId, u.acTitle
        from the_moveitem mi
            left join tpa_user u on u.anUserId = mi.anUserIns
        where mi.adTimeIns > getdate() - 365

        union

        select distinct u.anuserid, u.acUserId, u.acTitle
        from the_moveitem mi
            left join tpa_user u on u.anUserId = mi.anUserChg
        where mi.adTimeIns > getdate() - 365

    ) activeUsers365 on activeUsers365.anUserId = u.anUserId
```

while this one does instantly... (with no unions)

```sql
select u.anUserId, u.acUserId, u.acTitle, u.acActive, activeUsers365.* 
from tPA_User u
    left join (

        select distinct u.anuserid, u.acUserId, u.acTitle
        from the_moveitem mi
            left join tpa_user u on u.anUserId = mi.anUserIns
        where mi.adTimeIns > getdate() - 365

    ) activeUsers365 on activeUsers365.anUserId = u.anUserId
```

How can I accomplish this? I want to left join the union of two sub-queries, rather than have them be joins themselves.

Comment: It's tricky to tell what you're trying to achieve when the two queries being unioned appear identical. At the very least, `SELECT DISTINCT ... UNION SELECT DISTINCT ...` is redundant since `UNION` itself removes duplicates. Could you provide some sample data and expected results and an *explanation* of what you're trying to achieve rather than pursuing one *specific* solution that you believe will achieve your ends.

Comment: Please paste your plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and update your question with the link to your plan

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You answer made me realize that I am being stupid. I am doing double joins for no reason. The first table is the users table, while the sub-queries are the documents, where I AGAIN join the users. I removed the joins from the sub-queries and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sub-query left joins, as they are redundant.

The problem was not the unions, but rather the joins.

```sql
select u.anUserId, u.acUserId, u.acTitle, u.acActive, activeUsers365.* 
from tPA_User u
    left join (

        select mi.anUserIns userId
        from the_moveitem mi
        where mi.adTimeIns > getdate() - 365

        union

        select mi.anUserChg userId
        from the_moveitem mi
        where mi.adTimeIns > getdate() - 365

    ) activeUsers365 on activeUsers365.userId = u.anUserId
```